# Silverlight debug problem blank page

Tags: silverlight

I have a Visual Studio 2010 and silverlight 4 over it. When I'm trying to run a simple application hello world in a browser, it shows only the blank page.

The type 'Deployment' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

I think the problem is above but how can I solve it?

Comment: It shows blank page because of exception. Where do you use 'Deployment' in simple hello world application? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use silverlight with web application? When you create a silverlight app it have one web site associated. On the default.aspx, you have the object. Check the parameters off the object and verify if everything is ok and you have installed all components that support it.